# Automate testing of process flows in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber, bdd

I am building a educational service, and it is a rather process heavy application. I have a lot of user actions triggering various actions, some present, some future.

For example, when a student completes a lesson for his day, the following should happen:

- updating progress count for his user-module record
- checking if he has completed a particular module and progressing him to the next one (which in turn triggers more actions)
- triggering current emails to other users
- triggering FUTURE  emails to himself (ongoing lesson plans)
- creating range of other objects (grading todos by teachers)
- any other special case events

All these triggers are built into the observers of various objects, and the execution delayed using Sidekiq.

What is killing me is the testing, and the paranoia that I might breaking something whenever I push something. In the past, I do a lot of assertion and validations checks, and they were sufficient. For this project, I think this is not enough, given the elevated complexity.

As such, I would like to implement a testing framework, but after reading through the various options (Rspec, Cucumber), it is not immediately clear what I should be investing my effort into, given my rather specific needs, especially for the observers and scheduled events.

Any advice and tips on what approach and framework would be the most appropriate? Would probably save my ass in the very near future ;)

Not that it matters, but I am using Rails 3.2 / Mongoid. Happy to upgrade if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Testing can be a very subjective topic, with different approaches depending on the problems at hand.

I would say that given your primary need for testing end-to-end processes (often referred to as acceptance testing), you should definitely checkout something like cucumber or steak. Both allow you to drive a headless browser and run through your processes. This kind of testing will catch any big show stoppers and allow you to modify the system and be notified of breaks caused by your changes.

Unit testing, although very important, and should always be used in parallel with acceptance tests, isn't  for doing end-to-end testing, Its primarily for testing the output of specific methods in isolation

A common pattern to use is called Test Driven Development (TDD). In this, you write your acceptance tests first, in the "outer" test loop, and then code your app with Unit tests as part of the "inner" test loop. The idea being, when you've finished the code in the inner loop, then the outer loop should also pass, and you should have built up enough test coverage to have confidence that any future changes to the code will either pass/fail the test depending on if the original requirements are still met.

And lastly, a test suite is something that should grow and change as your app does. You may find that whole sections of your test suite can (and maybe should) be rewritten depending on how the requirements of the system change.

Answer (score 0):

Unit Testing is a must. you can use Rspec or TestUnit for that. It will give you atleast 80% confidence.

Enable "render views" for controller specs. You will catch syntax errors and simple logical  errors faster that way.There are ways to test sidekiq jobs. Have a look at [this](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing).

Once you are confident that you have enough unit tests, you can start looking into using cucumber/capybara or rspec/capybara for feature testing.